# What determines valid and invalid turing machines?

Tags: terminology, turing-machines

According to my understanding, a Turing machine that's valid *has* to have finite steps to finish a certain step. If this is right, what else determines the validity of a turing machine?

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of valid Turing machines. Which textbook are you using? Is it something that was mentioned in class?

Comment: I'm using Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser, our professor mentioned validity, but the book doesn't mention validity much.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the professor, then.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean a valid *encoding* of a machine?

Comment: Yea, I asked him several times already, he wasn't very clear as his English isn't very good. So this is why I turned over to Stack exchange :( I'll try looking for more info.

Comment: "has to have finite steps to finish a certain step" -- that sentence does not make any sense to me. Does "valid" just mean "well-defined" (which would, depending on the representation, include that it's actually a Turing machine, i.e. computes a computable function).

Comment: as RG writes there are some ways that an encoding of a turing machine might not be valid. it would be helpful if you talked about the context of his statement. eg "in theorem [x], the TM has to be valid" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to what I think you are referring to then your understanding seems correct.

A Turing machine has a precise definition: It is a tuple ... see for example 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition

Any system with the same components and conditions as described by the definition is indeed a Turing machine.  Anything else (which may at first glance appear to be a Turing machine) is not a Turing machine.

This distinction is to weed out some wrong intuitions.
Here is an example adopted from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435607/why-is-this-an-invalid-turing-machine

For example (given a polynomial P as input):

Start counter at 0
   Start Zero at False
   while(not Zero) {
      eval P(counter)
      if ^^ is 0 set Zero to True
   }
   Return True

Can be computed by a Turing machine (i.e. describes a valid Turing machine) while

Start list at []
   Start counter at 0
   while(true){
      add eval P(counter) to list
   }
   if any element of list is 0 return true else return false

Describes an invalid Turing machine, i.e. the code does not correspond to a Turing mahcine.

Well ^^ is all I can come up with.  Maybe it will help.

Comment: I honestly can't tell if this is the answer I'm looking for lol. I guess my conclusion by what my professor means by valid and invalid is if it's structured properly?